# Memory impact of assigning a new value to global variable

Tags: javascript, performance, memory-management

What happens when global variables are reassigned new values - would the old memory safely released or does it get leaked?

For example,

```
gUI = {};

function myFunc1() {
   gUI.selectedItem = new BigArray(1000);
}
function myFunc2() {
   gUI.selectedItem = new BigArray(1000);
}
function release() {
   gUI.selectedItem = null;
}
```

Would it be safe to call `myFunc1()` and `myFunc2()` one after the other immediately, or would it help to assign the variable to `null` first (before reassigning to another large object)?

I am purely interested in memory pressure and concerned about variable leaking the old memory when new value is assigned with `new`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript uses a garbage collector to reclaim memory of objects that are not accessible from any variables. So the old memory will be released automatically.